# Creating four different comparators

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator

How can I create 2 different comparators in order to sort 2 ArrayLists?
First list is sorted by the row number first then the column number.

```
[(0,1,A), (1,1,A), (1,2,A), (2,1,A)]  // Longest sequence of row-adjacent elements has size 2
```

Second list is sorted  by the column number first then the row number.

```
[(0,1,A), (1,1,A), (2,1,A), (1,2,A)]  // Longest sequence appears as adjacent elements, size 3
```

I have `ArrayList<RowColElem<T>> rowElems` that has to sort by the row number first then the column number; and `ArrayList<RowColElem<T>> colElems` that has to sort by the column number first then the row number. NOTE: both of the arraylists contain the same very elements but in unsorted order (i.e. in order that they were added) and I have to sort it but dont know how to implement 2 comparators. How should I create 2 comparators?

```
public class Board{
   ..............
..................
ArrayList<<T>> rowsElems; //Already contains information
ArrayList<<T>> colsElems; //Already contains information

public List<m<T>> ColOrder(){
      //needs to sort rowElems 
  }

  public List<<T>> elementsInColRowOrder(){
      //needs to sort colElems 
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you try [writing a `Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) and using `Collections.sort` for sorting the lists already?

Comment: My problem is what if i want to do sort more than 2 times? Should I create 4 different Comparator classes?

Comment: What do you mean by sorting more than 2 times? For achieving an ordering of "row number first then the column number", you only need one _sort_ but using a `Comparator` that first compares the `getRow()` values of different `RowColElem`s and only if the rows are equal, the `getCol()` values of those elements are compared. The `SENIORITY_ORDER` `Comparator` in the linked tutorial is an example where two properties of the objects being compared are used for defining the ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first comparator:

```
public class CompareRowCol<T> implements Comparator<RowColElem<T>> {
    public int compare(RowColElem<T> o1, RowColElem<T> o2) {
        int cmp = Integer.compare(o1.getRow(),o2.getRow());
        if(cmp != 0) {
            return cmp;
        } else {
            return Integer.compare(o1.getCol(),o2.getCol());
        }
    }
}
```

For the second you simply swap `getRow` with `getCol`:

```
public class CompareColRow<T> implements Comparator<RowColElem<T>> {
    public int compare(RowColElem<T> o1, RowColElem<T> o2) {
        int cmp = Integer.compare(o1.getCol(),o2.getCol());
        if(cmp != 0) {
            return cmp;
        } else {
            return Integer.compare(o1.getRow(),o2.getRow());
        }
    }
}
```

this one gives priority to the column over the row.

You can sort lists using the [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method:

```
Collections.sort(rowsElems,new CompareRowCol<T>());//create new comparator and sort
```

This will alter `rowElems` such that its elements are sorted after the call.

It is however adviseable, **not** to use two lists containing the same data, since this will make it harder to remain consistent between the two. Use one list that you then clone and sort.

**Explanation**

I will only explain the first comparator, since the other is its dual, and the analogy is easy.

First we compare the two rows of the two given items:

```
int cmp = Integer.compare(o1.getRow(),o2.getRow());
```

`cmp` is an integer, that is negative if the row number of `o1` is less than the row number of `o2`; zero if both numbers are equal; and positive if the row number of `o1` is greater than the row number of `o2`.

Next we perform a check:

```
if(cmp != 0)
```

if `cmp` is equal to zero, it means that both row numbers are equal, and we thus have to test on column number. If however `cmp` is not equal to zero, the row numbers differ, and therefore we can immediately return the result `cmp`.

Now if both row numbers are equal, we perform a comparison on the column numbers:

```
return Integer.compare(o1.getCol(),o2.getCol());
```

we can immediately return the result, because if both column numbers are equal, the two items are considered to be equal as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @CommuSoft. Before I accept the answer, could you please explain these lines?: `int cmp = Integer.compare(o1.getRow(),o2.getRow());
        if(cmp != 0) {
            return cp;`

Comment: @John: there was a typo: it is `return cmp`. Explanation added.